# How do I update a CentOS server's time from an authoritative time server?

Tags: centos, time-synchronization

I have CentOS machine and each time I've noticed that the server loses correct time after a while. It is usually behind by several minutes after time passes from having manually set the correct time. Is there a mechanism whereby I can update the server with the time from a specific time server?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use the `ntp` daemon. Run `yum install ntp` and ensure that the service is started via `ntsysv` or `chkconfig ntpd on`.

To get an immediate sync, run `ntpdate time.apple.com` (or something similar).

Comment: @ewhite I did yum and it is show ing is also already install. so what should be my next step? How to config my time to point to the ntp server?

Comment: Try `/sbin/service ntpd stop`, followed by `ntpdate time.apple.com` and then `/sbin/service ntpd start`

Comment: @ewwhite Another solution is to run `ntpdate -b -u time.nist.gov` which will attempt to use a separate port than the ntpd daemon is using.

Comment: For me `ntpdate` worked without specifying a timeserver.

Comment: In 2018 it is systemctl can you update?

Comment: On CentOS 7.2.1511, the ntpdate is installed at /sbin/ntpdate. So, I had to run sudo /sbin/ntpdate time.apple.com to fix its time.

Answer (score 109):

You need to install and configure ntp.

```
yum install ntp
chkconfig ntpd on
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
service ntpd start
```

should get things set up and running. You may find that the ntp package is already installed and just needs configuring.

Comment: If the computer being changed is not a VM, then I `hwclock -w` after the `ntpdate` command.  This means the next time the computer reboots, your clock will be less out-of-sync than it is now.

Comment: @lain I already check is install but what to config to point to the ntp server and keep it remain syn?

Comment: @user111196: JUst perform the chkconfig, ntpdate and service commands above.

Comment: @lain what I am interest to learn on which time will it syn to is it my current time zone is it?

Comment: Yes, the time will be correct for the time zone that your system is set to.

Answer (score 14):

Yes.

[NTP.](http://ntp.org/)

```
yum install ntp
chkconfig ntpd on
```

Do an initial sync, with

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

and start the time daemon with:

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

Comment: how to do the initial sync any command? You mean just run ntpdate pool.ntp.org but where is the time set?

Comment: ntpdate sets the time.

Comment: ntpdate set the date according to the server's time zone settings rite

Comment: ntpdate sets the hardware clock.  Whatever you're doing with /etc/timezone is a bit more userspacey.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to configure ntpd for the server.  I suspect it is already installed but needs to be configured.  Note: if it is a virtual server, you probably have the option of syncing with the virtual host.

Answer (score 3):

For centos 7.x installation:

```
yum install ntp
systemctl enable ntpd
```

initial sync, with:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

start the daemon with:

```
systemctl start ntpd
```

Comment: CentOS 7 systems use chrony by default, so if you want to switch NTP clients you should disable or remove chrony first before installing ntpd.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have CentOS 7 and it didn't had chrony by default.

Comment: @Unicornist You are only guaranteed to get chrony if you install from official CentOS media. If someone else performs the installation for you, or you use custom media, then you might not get it.

Answer (score 2):

[ntpd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-ntp-to-synchronize-server-clock/).

Ntpd does exactly what you're looking for - synchronizes your system clock with one or more known-good time servers.

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are two ways. NTP daemon and the ntpdate command. The most important difference is that ntpdate will synchronize the time at once even though it means that the system time will change. On the other hand NTP daemon will take care of the time synchronization and it will adjust the time by small steps - you can think about it like slowing down/speeding up the time of the computer to synchronize it to the correct time. Thats why people suggest to do the initial synchronization by ntpdate and then leave it to ntp daemon.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `Centos 8`, I just start/enble `chronyd` like below:

```
systemctl start chronyd
systemctl enable chronyd
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea I'd use NTP, install ntp with yum and turn it on.

```
yum install ntp
chkconfig ntpd on
```

Then sync it to any ntp server of your liking with the `ntpdate` command

Answer (score 0):

Also if using CPanel like I was and had this issue. I think using rdate. Changing to ntpd as per above fixes all issues with email, especially dovecot,etc.