# "Issued certificate not yet valid." with wget?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, time, wget

I am getting the following error when using wget to fetch a file:

```
  Issued certificate not yet valid.
To connect to www.atlassian.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

Testing with openssl returns a similar message:

```
Verify return code: 9 (certificate is not yet valid)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your system clock is likely set in the past.

Comment: Well, so easy ... Thanks a lot (specially on embedded devices it is good to check if RTC is set correctly ...)

Answer (score 2):

When [checking the ssl certificate 'notBefore' date with openssl](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Check-SSL-Certificate-Expiration-Date-from-the-Linux-Shell) it was valid... It turns out my calling machine's system time was way in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Sync system clock:

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was system clock out of sync.   I wanted to also provide a lync to the fix (setup ntp).  [How do I update a CentOS server's time from an authoritative time server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/368602/how-do-i-update-a-centos-servers-time-from-an-authoritative-time-server)

Comment: please try to avoid link only answers. provide full answer into your post, with reference links.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that following this tutorial:
[Network - NTP](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp)

Check if your system clock is correct:

```
timedatectl status
```

```
Local time: Fr 2018-02-23 08:47:13 UTC
                   Universal time: Fr 2018-02-23 08:47:13 UTC
                         RTC time: Fr 2018-02-23 08:47:13
                        Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
        System clock synchronized: yes
 systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                  RTC in local TZ: no
```

If not, install chrony:

```
sudo apt install chrony
```

And start **chronyd** - the actual daemon to sync and serve via the NTP protocol

```
sudo chronyd
```